# Warning Attempting to move a fully simulated skeletal mesh VehicleMesh. Please use the Teleport flag. Issue

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Iam getting this error in the console of unreal engine 4.24 : 
`Warning Attempting to move a fully simulated skeletal mesh VehicleMesh. Please use the Teleport flag.`
Iam trying to get this working for a race systeem with AI. If iam in the car it works fine. But when the AI 'drives' it won't work and it gets that error. Iam unable to provide a download link for the project because my project is a bit too big (its almost 300gb with all the assets).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but it has still no answer(s).

You find the Teleport flag on nodes that change the transform of the car: position/rotations that make the car move.
Here are 2 examples of nodes that have the Teleport flag.

[image: Teleport flags]